# jsonpickle/json function input utf-8, output unicode?

Tags: python, json, encoding, jsonpickle

Wrote the following two functions for storing and retrieving any Python (built-in or user-defined) object with a combination of json and jsonpickle (in 2.7)

```
def save(kind, obj):
    pickled = jsonpickle.encode(obj)
    filename = DATA_DESTINATION[kind] \\returns file destination to store json
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        open(filename, 'w').close()
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(pickled, f)

def retrieve(kind):
    filename = DATA_DESTINATION[kind] \\returns file destination to store json
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            pickled = json.load(f)
            unpickled = jsonpickle.decode(pickled)
            print unpickled
```

I haven't tested these two functions with user-defined objects, but when i attempt to save() a built-in dictionary of strings, (ie. {'Adam': 'Age 19', 'Bill', 'Age 32'}), and i retrieve the same file, i get the same dictionary back in unicode, {u'Adam': u'Age 19', u'Bill', u'Age 32'}. I thought json/jsonpickle encoded by default to utf-8, what's the deal here?

[UPDATE]: Removing all jsonpickle encoding/decoding does not effect output, still in unicode, seems like an issue with json? Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode the unicode sting after calling loads().

```
json.loads('"\\u79c1"').encode('utf-8')
```

Now you have a normal string  again.

Comment: unicode is a different type of object [link](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support)

Comment: So what. It's still a normal string.

Comment: :D yes it is a string. But it's encoding is unicode, not utf-8. If you want utf-8 encoding, you have to encode it. I mean with normal string a str object. Python 2 distinguishes between unicode strings and 'normal' strings. type(u'abc') >>> unicode type('abc') >>> str

Comment: Both `unicode` and `str` are normal strings. The difference is that `unicode` is more accurate since bytestrings need to specify an encoding.

Comment: His input is an utf-8 str object. The output of load is an unicode object, but he want a utf-8 str object again, so he has to encode the unicode object to a str object. What is the problem with this? ---    I preferably would like to get back the same encoding i put in? – zhuyxn 1 hour ago

Comment: it seems like adding `.encode('utf-8')` does not change the output which is for some reason still in unicode. Using `json.load` rather than `json.loads` since I'm loading from a file (not sure if this is accurate) but `loads` causes an error.

Answer (score 10):

```
import jsonpickle
import json

jsonpickle.set_preferred_backend('json')
jsonpickle.set_encoder_options('json', ensure_ascii=False)
print( jsonpickle.encode( { "value" : "значение"}) )
```

{"value": "значение"}

Answer (score 0):

> I thought json ... encoded by default to utf-8, what's the deal here?

No, it encodes to ASCII. And it decodes to `unicode`.

```
>>> json.dumps(u'私')
'"\\u79c1"'
>>> json.loads('"\\u79c1"')
u'\u79c1'
```

Comment: Oh, just read the documentation more clearly, thanks! but how do i fix this issue? pickled = `json.load(f, encoding = "utf-8")` does not seem to do the trick ):

Comment: The issue is your code. You need to make it work with `unicode`s.

Comment: I preferably would like to get back the same encoding i put in?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that json, as a serialization format, is not expressive enough to carry the information about the original type of strings. In other words, if you have a json string `a` you can't tell whether is has been originated from a python string `"a"` or from a python *unicode* string `u"a"`.

Indeed, you can read in the [documentation of the json module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dump) about the option `ensure_ascii`. Basically, depending on where you are going to write the generated json, you might tolerate a unicode string, or need an ascii string with all incoming unicode characters properly escaped.

For example:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'a':'b'})
'{"a": "b"}'
>>> json.dumps({'a':u'b'}, ensure_ascii=False)
u'{"a": "b"}'
>>> json.dumps({'a':u'b'})
'{"a": "b"}'
>>> json.dumps({u'a':'b'})
'{"a": "b"}'
>>> json.dumps({'a':u'\xe0'})
'{"a": "\\u00e0"}'
>>> json.dumps({'a':u'\xe0'}, ensure_ascii=False)
u'{"a": "\xe0"}'
```

As you can see, depending on the value of `ensure_ascii` you end up with an ascii json string or a unicode one, but the components of the original objects are all flattened to the same common encoding. Look at `{"a": "b"}` case in particular.

`jsonpickle` simply makes use of `json` as its underlying serialization engine, adding no extra metadata to keep track of the original string types, therefore you are in fact loosing information along the way.

```
>>> jsonpickle.encode({'a': 'b'})
'{"a": "b"}'
>>> jsonpickle.encode({'a': u'b'})
'{"a": "b"}'
>>> jsonpickle.encode({u'a': 'b'})
'{"a": "b"}'
```